# Spread omit doesn't omit property inside action handler

Tags: javascript, redux

I feel i'm going crazy, the following code just doesn't work when used in reducer, however running it with the exact same variables in the console or playground works absolutely perfect.

```
[MutationTypes.DELETE_GOALS_SUCCESS]: (state, { payload }) => {
  //payload is {deleted_goals: [1, 2, 3]}, goals is {1: {...}, 2: {...}, ... n: {...}}
  const goals = { ...state.goals };
  const newGoals = payload.deleted_goals.reduce((acc, id) => {
    const { [id]: omitted, ...newAcc } = acc; //newAcc still contains "id" key
    console.log(
      "After spread",
      "New goals:",
      newAcc,
      "Old goals:",
      acc, //acc and newAcc are the same aside from different pointers
      "Removed goal",
      omitted,
    );
    return newAcc;
  }, goals);
  return {
    ...state,
    goals: newGoals,
  };
},
```

The `const { [id]: omitted, ...newAcc } = acc;` part is what just doesn't work as intended. newAcc for some reason still keeps containing `id` key, so it remains unchanged every iteration. The `id` key is included in goals object, i can log `omitted` object.
As i said i can run the exact same line of code anywhere else with the exact same variables and it will work perfectly. This might be something with redux or my implementation of reducer, however i just cannot imagine what can be wrong and how it can cause such consequences. State is just plain object, state.goal is also just plain object, i'm even making shallow copy of it. I can `JSON.stringify` them, copy paste somewhere else and then omit the same way i do here and it will work.
Any idea what might cause this strange interaction? There are multiple workarounds to do this without spread, like using delete operator, or constructing new object from scratch but i want to know why the hell can object become "immune" to spread destructuring.

I've tried to omit with spread on fresh object inside both action handler and reduce callback and it worked, looks like there is something with this particular object ( state.goals ). However it is just map like object structured like that: `{id1: {goalwithid}, id2:{goalwithid2} ...}` id1, id2 etc are numbers.

Just tried deepcloning object (replaced `const goals = { ...state.goals };` with `const goals = _.cloneDeep(state.goals)` and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this:

```
[MutationTypes.DELETE_GOALS_SUCCESS]: (state, { payload }) => {
  //payload is {deleted_goals: [1, 2, 3]}, goals is {1: {...}, 2: {...}, ... n: {...}}
  const goals = state.goals;
  const newGoals = Object.keys(goals).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if(payload.deleted_goals.includes(parseInt(key))) {
      return acc;
    } else {
      return (acc[key] = goals[key], acc);
    }
  }, {})

  return {
    ...state,
    goals: newGoals,
  };
},
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, thank you. However i want to know why the initial way ( which is much more elegant imo ) doesn't work.

Comment: @Supremus are the elements inside `deleted_goals` numbers or strings?

Comment: It is numbers. Also js detects without any problem which key i mean, it sucessfully sets omitted value to goals[id] value but doesn't omit it from goals.

Comment: You might want to add `parseInt` if you are using my way(updated my answer). Regarding the problem in your code, I'm not completely sure but you can create a stackblitz instance replicating this issue and I'll look into it.

Comment: Can you also update the question with the logs you are logging inside `reduce`?

Comment: I already added parseInt, thanks for typescript. The problem is goal object is pretty big ( about 100 keys and every value also has about 10+ properties ) and it contains some information i wouldn't post here. Abd i swear the logs are as i describe, acc is identical to newAcc. Object.keys(acc).length === Object.keys(newAcc).length is true. omitted is goal[id] value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211015/discussion-between-supremus-and-ramesh).